# Dojo TabContainer doesn't show control buttons correctly until after I do an Inspect Element

Tags: dojo, tabcontainer

I'm using ArcGIS API for Javascript

[ArcGIS Javascript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/layout_MapContainerSplitLeft.html)

[image]

The formatting for the **TabContainer** is incorrect. However, after I do an "Inspect Element", the formatting corrects itself

[image]

Here's the code I use to create TabContainer:

```
    <div id="tab_plot_info" dojoType="dijit/layout/TabContainer" onClick="tabclick" style="width: 100%;"
        doLayout="false">
        <div id="ploinfoTab" dojoType="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Plot Information" selected="true"></div>
        <div id="devcodeTab" dojoType="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Development Code"></div>
        <div id="devcodeprojectTab" dojoType="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Development Project"></div>
        <div id="onwaniTab" dojoType="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Onwnai Address"></div>
        <div id="communityfacilityTab" dojoType="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Community Facility"></div>
    </div>

map.infoWindow.on("show", function () {
        registry.byId("tab_plot_info").resize();
    });
    map.infoWindow.resize(415, 200);
    map.infoWindow.setContent(registry.byId("tab_plot_info").domNode);
    map.infoWindow.setTitle("Identify Results")
```

So what's going here and how do I fix the **TabContainer** formatting? Thanks!

Comment: Try calling resize() at the end, after setContent() and setTitle().

Comment: @pgianna I tried and its working. Thank you so much.